# What is a (reasonably) secure and automated way to backup my mysql database using (any) free cloud/online services?

Tags: backup, security, mysql, scripts

I have a mysql database that I use for personal devlopment. I would like to back-it up online using any ***free (in cost)*** online storage. (dropbox, google-drive etc...)

I am assuming a shell script would do the job.

The algorithm I am seeing work is:

1.Backup database to local disk

2.Encrypt file using pgp or reasonably equivalent.

3.Upload file to suggested cloud service.

Does anyone have any methods they have used in the past for something similar?
The most important things here are... Free (in cost), Automation (using chron or /init.d ), and securtiy. If my database fell into "the badguys hands" can i protect it from prying eyes (reasonably).

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Oh I should add this is on a sever with NO GUI.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Have a look at grive Ubuntu package. It might be what you are looking for. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/grive/

Answer (score 1):

I would combine parts 1 and 2.  MySql allows you to take encrypted backups as [detailed here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.10/en/meb-encryption.html):

```
mysqlbackup --backup-image=/backups/image.enc --encrypt
--key-file=/meb/key  --backup-dir=/var/tmp/backup  backup-to-image
```

The next bit would be to push the image up to a cloud service.  This comes down to personal preference. If you like Dropbox, it has a [headless daemon](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx); For a commandline Google Drive client, have a look at InSync or Grive.